# How to make RecyclerView with Composable ViewHolder render faster?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewholder

As per https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-ui#compose-recyclerview, the composable ViewHolder that can be used in RecyclerView is as below

```
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewCompositionStrategy

class MyComposeViewHolder(
    val composeView: ComposeView
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(composeView) {

    init {
        composeView.setViewCompositionStrategy(
            ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed
        )
    }

    fun bind(input: String) {
        composeView.setContent {
            MdcTheme {
                Text(input)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like, every time it is `bind` the composable `setContent` (i.e. redraw again).

I measure the speed using [Profile GPU Rendering](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering#profile_rendering), it clearly show that the Hybrid of ReyclerView+ComposeViewHolder is slower than pure RecyclerView or LazyColumn.

[image]

You can get the [design here](https://github.com/elye/demo_android_jetpack_compose_recyclerview_lazycolumnfor)

How can we speed up the Hybrid RecyclerView+ComposeViewHolder?

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of RecyclerView (1.3.0-alpha02) and Compose (1.2.0-beta02) have improved support and performance for Compose when used in RecyclerView thanks to the PoolingContainer library it uses. No need to dispose nor set the `ViewCompositionStrategy`. Note that the content in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-ui#compose-recyclerview is only needed if you are using stable versions of the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Please run release build of the application with R8 enabled. This increases performance significantly.

Comment: I have minifyEnabled true , and see `app:minifyDebugWithR8` triggered. So I believe R8 is enabled. The result is the same, no improvement to the Hybrid version.

Comment: And is it a debug or a release build?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a diff view composition strategy, one that is tied to the lifecycle of the fragment/activity. That way your composable isn't based on attach/detatch of the view which happens a lot